# How to record a emphasized sentence where pause after each word?

Tags: punctuation

I saw the title of an article, which is “[Stop. Using. Periods. Period.](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2016/06/13/stop-using-periods-period-2/)”
In literature, does the writer use period to record a emphasized sentence where pause after each word?
e.g. “You. Are. In. Big. Trouble,” she said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the convention when the speaker is speaking each word with emphasis and a break between them.

A pause between each word alone is typically "You -- are -- in -- big -- trouble."